# binding a lvalue expression of type T&&

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, lvalue

In the last few days I've been trying to grasp an apparently trivial principle behind lvalue/rvalue references. Let us define a new rvalue reference:

```
int&& x = 12;
```

`x` is therefore an lvalue expression of type `int&&`. Since `x` is a lvalue, it can be bound to a lvalue reference of the same type, i.e., a lvalue reference of type `int&&`. Such a lvalue reference would be defined as:

```
int&& & ref_x = x; // non-working code, just for the sake of explanation
```

Of course, it is not possible to explicitly define a reference to a reference, and the correct way to perform the binding is as follows:

```
int& ref_x = x;
```

C++ Primer reports the following about using references as initializers:

> when we use a reference as an initializer, we are really using the
>   object to which the reference is bound

On the other hand, the lvalue reference must match the type of the lvalue expression. What am I missing? Is reference collapsing involved in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `x` (as an expression) is an expression of type `int`. The type of the value of an expression is never a reference. In fact, `x` is also an *lvalue*, since it is a named thing.

Also, there are no references to references, for the same reason: References bind to values, and values are never references.

If you're ever confused, just keep telling yourself: The value of an expression is always an object type. Whether the value *category* of an expression is l or r only determines what sort of things the value can bind to; it has no effect on its type.

Comment: What about the following statement from Scott Meyer's "universal references in C++11" article: _"Because the lvalueness or rvalueness of an expression is independent of its type, it’s possible to have lvalues whose type is rvalue reference, and it’s also possible to have rvalues of the type rvalue reference"_?

Comment: @burton0: I don't know. Maybe he means that a variable which is an rvalue reference can form an expression that is an lvalue?

Comment: "The type of the value of an expression is never a reference." I'm not sure what you mean with *type of the value of an expression*, but the type of `static_cast<int&>(x)` is an lvalue reference, and its value category is lvalue. Scott Meyers also uses [casts as an example](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

Comment: @DyP: Hm... maybe we should look this up in the standard. To my mind, the type of your cast expression is indeed `int&`, but the type of the *value* that you obtain when you evaluate the expression is `int`.

Comment: [expr]/5 "If an expression initially has the type “reference to `T`”, the type is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis." (that's the first step, at least)

Comment: @DyP: Are you suggesting that the expression `x` is implictly adjusted to `int` just before being bound to `ref_x`?

Comment: No, the result of `static_cast<int&>(x)` is still just `int`. Anyone have a link to that article handy? A *name* can have type rvalue reference such that `decltype(a)` is `int &&`, but that's a special case of `decltype`. The expression `a` is still an lvalue of type `int`, so `decltype((a))` with more parens is `int &`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Scott Meyer's article is available [here](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)

Comment: @Potatoswatter I've disguised the link ;) He says "`Widget var2 = static_cast<Widget&&>(var1); // the cast expression yields an rvalue, but its type is rvalue reference (to Widget)`" Ad type of the cast: [expr.static.cast]/1 "The result of the expression `static_cast<T>(v)` is the result of converting the expression `v` to type `T`." But unfortunately, I can't find more on the *type of the expression `static_cast<int&>(v)`*. Where is it specified that the type will be adjusted from `int&` to `int`?

Comment: @burton0 Yes. In fact, I think every mention of the name `x` after the declaration is an *id-expression* (therefore an expression), which means whenever `x` occurs, its type is `int`. As Potatoswatter pointed out, `decltype(e)` is special: for an unparenthesized *id-expression*, it doesn't use the type of (the expression) `e`, but "the type of the entity named by `e`". Therefore `decltype(x)` is a reference to `int`.

Comment: @DyP That's just wrong. The type of `static_cast< Widget && >(…)` is the same as `static_cast< Widget >(…)`. Meyers is either in the wrong frame of mind there and/or isn't even trying to be precise about the type system.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I'd appreciate if you could give me a reference to the Standard, because besides what I mentioned about the *result* of `static_cast`, I'm unable to find specifications about the *type of the `static_cast` expression*.

Comment: @DyP See 5.2.9/1 and 5/5, which forbids expressions from having reference types.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Thank you. Do you mean [expr]/5 also applies to the result of `static_cast`? I was under the impression "expression initially has the type" wouldn't apply to the direct type of the expression `static_cast<T>(v)` (as it is a resulting type, not an initial type).

Comment: @DyP That's not the sense of "initial" there, but others have been confused by that as well, and the "before further analysis." It goes like this: The syntactic construct `static_cast<…>(…)` is a subexpression. When identifying its type, if you arrive at a reference type, remove the reference.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Thank you. Then, Meyers is probably just imprecise: "it’s possible to have lvalues whose type is rvalue reference, and it’s also possible to have rvalues of the type rvalue reference:" but the first one isn't possible even with casts and even if we assume some *could* have reference type; `?value` is a category of an expression, and as an *id-expression*, it doesn't have ref type. And a cast to an lvalue category rvalue reference just isn't possible.

Comment: To sum up, `x`is indeed a lvalue expression of type `int`. Moreover, it cannot exist a `?value` expression of type `reference to T`. Correct?