# What's the type of the function call expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, reference, expression

This is a language lawyer question. Clause 5p5 in C++11 reads:

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” (8.3.2, 8.5.3), the type is adjusted to T prior to
>   any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and the
>   expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression.

On the other hand, §5.2.2p3 states:

> If the postfix-expression designates a destructor (12.4), the type of the function call expression is void;
>   otherwise, the type of the function call expression is the return type of the statically chosen function (i.e.,
>   ignoring the virtual keyword), even if the type of the function actually called is different. This type shall
>   be an object type, a reference type or the type void.

Consider this piece of code:

```
int& f();
f();  // What is the type of this expression?
```

Comment: Just have thought about the same thing ;) I think `f()` yields an lvalue (expression) of type `int`.

Comment: I knew I had this discussion before, but on the topic of `static_cast`. See [these comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816713/binding-a-lvalue-expression-of-type-t#comment27762558_18816825)

Comment: @DyP Well, the problem seems to be that there is no precise definition of "initially" and "prior to any further analysis".

Comment: I agree, it's at least confusing. I think once you put `f()` as a sub-expression in a context, you could apply "initially" to the analysis of the super-expression. For example: `f() = 42`

Comment: The standard explicitely states: "the type of the function call expression is the return type [...] This type shall be [...] a reference type [,,,]" Doesn't this contradict clause 5p5?

Comment: And reading §5.3.3p2 about `sizeof`: "When applied to a reference [...]" Is this then really possible? Is the committee also confused by their wordings?

Comment: I think that's redundant, yes. But maybe it's there to explicitly state that you shouldn't be able to get the size of a reference.

Comment: I see no problem. The type of a call of a function returning T is T. The type of a destructor call is `void`. The wording about "actually called" covers a call of virtual function with covariant result.

Answer (score 4):

This was corrected post publication of the standard, in [DR 1261](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1261).  Draft n3485 reads:

> [...] otherwise, the type of the function call expression is the return type of the statically chosen function (i.e.,
>   ignoring the `virtual` keyword), even if the type of the function actually called is different. This **return** type
>   shall be an object type, a reference type or *`cv`* `void`.

(my emphasis; not in your quote).

The two paragraphs are now compatible; the (initial) type of the function call expression is now `int &`, which gets adjusted to `int` and value-category lvalue immediately.  A similar process occurs with a function returning a qualified type, which has the advantage that we don't need to worry about lvalue-to-reference conversion:

```
const int g();
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(g()), int>::value, "!!!");
```

Comment: @DyP brilliant, thanks.  So the standard is erroneous but was corrected post-publication.

Comment: @DyP But this introduces a similar problem in C++14: `const int g(); g();` What's the type of the expression `g()`?

Comment: @MWid `g()` has initial type `const int`, adjusted to `int`.

Comment: @ecatmur Well, from a logical point of view, this doesn't make sense: If an expression has some type T then it has another type U. Or put it differently: Where does the standard distinguish between the _initial_ type and the (real) type?

Comment: @MWid The initial type looks to be called *result type* in some places (e.g. 5.2.2p10); experiment confirms this (e.g. 20.8.2p3).

Comment: @ecatmur: re "a similar process", could you elaborate with some standard ref? for while `int const` rvalue is the same as `int` rvalue, a `MyClass const` rvalue is not the same as `MyClass` rvalue wrt. to what you can do with it. such as calling a non-`const` member function.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf In CWP1261, this adjustment is only applied to non-class types, [expr]/5: "If a prvalue initially has the type “cv T,” where T is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis."

Answer (score 0):

The type of `f()` is `int`; its value category is lvalue. You can demonstrate this fact:

```
int& f();
static_assert(std::is_same<int&,decltype((f()))>::value,"EXPLODE");
```

per C++11 §7.1.6.2 [dcl.type.simple]/4 "...if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`".

Comment: -1 It's an extraordinary claim, requiring extraordinary evidence. No such is given.

Comment: I think your reasoning is wrong: Because of reference collapsing you cannot draw any conclusions about the type of `e` from the result of `decltype(e)`.

Comment: @MWid I'm not understanding. Could you perhaps give an example of an expression `e` that is *not* an lvalue of integer type for which `decltype((e))` is `int&`? Alternatively, explain where reference collapsing is involved in my sample code.

Comment: @Casey If `foo()` was of type `int&`, then for `decltype`, `T` was `int&`, and `T&` would probably collapse to `int&`, yielding the same result as if `T` was `int`. The additional parentheses could change the type, as now `foo()` is only a sub-expression of `decltype`. They however don't have an effect on the result AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Example code:

```
int& foo() { static int x; return x; }
int bar() { return 0; }

template< class Type >
struct Is_ref_ { static const bool yes = false; };

template< class Type >
struct Is_ref_<Type&> { static const bool yes = true; };

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
auto main() -> int
{
    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << "Function calls foo versus bar:" << endl;
    cout << Is_ref_<decltype(foo())>::yes << endl;
    cout << Is_ref_<decltype(bar())>::yes << endl;

    int a;
    int& b = a;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "lvalue versus ref:" << endl;
    cout << Is_ref_<decltype(a)>::yes << endl;
    cout << Is_ref_<decltype(b)>::yes << endl;
}
```

Output with Visual C++ 12.0 and with MinGW g++ 4.7.2:

> Function calls foo versus bar:
>   true
>   false
>
> lvalue versus ref:
>   false
>   true

Comment: Couldn't this also work with reference collapsing? `decltype` in the case of `foo()` is specified as `T&`; if `T` is a reference type, `T& &` should yield a reference, no?

Comment: @DyP I agree. Reference collapsing makes it impossible to reason about the type of an expression `e` by using `decltype`.

Comment: Well I dunno. `decltype` is very good at distinguishing a reference type as such, e.g. an `int a;` versus an `int& b = a`.

Comment: Well there are special rules if the expression in the parentheses of the `decltype` is an id-expression. That's not the case for a function call.